# View not completely loaded before transition?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller, segue

I have a modal view controller and a master view controller. When I open the modal view controller, everything works fine. But when I press the back button, the Master View Controller isn't loaded and loads itself immediately after the transition is done. Is there anyway I can fix this issue? Would I use prepareforsegue? A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using presentModalViewController (or the storyboard equivalent) all you have to do is have the modal view controller call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]`. The master view controller will not have been removed from memory, so no setup is necessary.

Comment: That works for me except how would I change the transition style? I tried doing self.modalTransitionStyle... but it didn't work!

Comment: Just performing a seguewithidentfier. Here's the code: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TableView" sender:nil];

Comment: It looks like you're using a storyboard then, so just select the segue in the storyboard and change its transition style in the property editor. If you aren't using storyboard post the segue declaration code.

Comment: I changed the transition style, and the problem still exists about the lag.

Comment: Is master view controller presenting the modal view controllers? If it is, then it should stay loaded behind the modal view controllers.

Comment: I had a small error in the code, your code did work! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try to do everything in your   viewWillApear: cause when it when modelViewController got dismiss viewWillApear: will call and load the load functionality there only :